# How do I make a submit button using devexpress and knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devexpress, submit, devextreme

So I have an app that shows expenses of a person. I made the view to add a new expense, but I don't know how to make the save button so it saves the expense in the db and redirects to the list of expenses.

The view has many fields like this:

```
    <div id="selBxChSt" data-bind="dxLookup: {
        dataSource: dsExpenses,
        valueExpr: 'NAME',
        displayExpr: 'NAME',
        title: 'Expense',
        searchEnabled: true,
        value: selectedExpense
        }">
    </div>
```

And not only dxLookup, also dxTagBox,dxDateBox and dxTextArea.

I made the reset button, to set all fields to their default value. But I don't know how to save them to the firebird db.

This is the html for the button:

```
<div class="Column" data-bind="dxButton: {icon: 'todo', text: 'Save', type: 'normal', onClick: expenseSave}"></div>
```

So now I have to make a function in knockoutJS to save all the things the user chooses from the lookups.

I have no idea how to do this, I'm new to knockout.js and devexpress, so any idea or tips would be amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement "old-school" form that submits data to a server-side go this way:

1. Wrap all editors and submit button with the `form` tag.
2. Use the [useSubmitBehavior](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxButton/Configuration/#useSubmitBehavior) option for dxButton.
3. Set the [name](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTextBox/Configuration/#name) option for editors.

Your code should be like below:

```
<form action="your-action" method="post" data-bind="event: { submit: onFormSubmit }">
    <div data-bind="dxTextBox: { name: 'login' }"></div>
    <!-- other editors... -->
    <div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Submit', useSubmitBehavior: true }"></div>
</form>
```

View model:

```
viewModel.onFormSubmit = function() {
    // Here you can implement a custom logic before submit. Validate editors, for instance.
};
```

Refer this [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdEXzv), as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just have one more question. How do I insert that data into the db?

Comment: It depends on your backend. The approach I described allows you to send a data to server-side. Then, you can retrieve the data from $_POST array(If you are using php). In this case, make sure, your form method is `post`.

Comment: I left a question below, can you help me pleasee?

Comment: `$.ajax` request isn't necessary in this case. Did you set the `action` attribute for your form? I mean, `<form action="your-url.php" method="post"></form>`. Also, you can get rid of the  `chModel.onFormSubmit` method.

Comment: I'm really confused. At action should I put the file Utils.php, where the saveExpenses method is?

Comment: I think so. Do not forget to call the `saveExpenses` function.